# what is the best way to write this:

Tags: javascript

```
let valor = value.replace("'","")
            valor=valor.replace('"',"")
```

//or

```
name=value.replace("'","").replace('"',"")
```

Comment: This isn't really a coding question. But from my experience calling replace().replace() is cleaner. But both work and both are okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better option might be to use a single `.replace` instead, and use a regular expression to match either `'` or `"`:

```
const valor = value.replace(/['"]/g, '');
```